# Excel VBA - Use VlookUp Inside Is Error

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I need to do a vlookup through a range of cells, and depending on it returning a value or a #N/A, I want to do some action on it.

I tried to place the vlookup inside the iserror function but that didn't work.

This is what i tried next but is also not working:

```
Set costCentreMapping = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\mapping.xlsx")
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Dim CostCentreRange As Range
Set CostCentreRange = Range("A4:E2967")

    Set test1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(appid, CostCentreRange, 2, False)

            If IsError(test1) Then 

                appid.Offset(columnoffset:=15) = "value1"

            End If
```

What do you recommed me to do?

Thanks

Comment: to do it that way you need to remove the `.WorksheetFunction` from both VLOOKUPS.  This will allow the passing of the error into the variable.

Comment: doesn't VLOOKUP return a value?  I don't think you necessarily need to 'set' test1 and test 2 (albeit not tested)

Comment: So only Application.VLookup ?

Comment: @AntónioPires what exactly are you `Set`ting with the `VLookup` ? what value are you trying to get from it ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm using the value of first argument to look for it in another table. If that value doesn't exist in that table I want to do some action, and if it exists i want to do some different action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

```
Set costCentreMapping = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\mapping.xlsx")

Dim CostCentreRange As Range
Set CostCentreRange = costCentreMapping.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4:E2967")

Dim test1 as variant 'the variable must be a variant to accept an error.
    test1 = Application.VLookup(appid, CostCentreRange, 2, False)

            If IsError(test1) Then 

                appid.Offset(columnoffset:=15) = "value1"

            End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code (that you posted above) could look like the shorter version below:

```
If IsError(Application.VLookup(appid, CostCentreRange, 2, False)) Then ' <-- not found in VLookup
    appid.Offset(, 15) = "value1"

    If customercountry = "UNITED KINGDOM" Then
        If IsError(Application.VLookup(billService, billableRange, 3, False)) Then
            appid.Offset(, 14) = "value2"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This is what i had in the first attempt. But it results on an error, it doesn't run.

Comment: This will give an error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument  if your range object(s) are `Nothing`.

Comment: @DavidZemens are you referring to me or Antonio ?

Comment: @ShaiRado both :)  If the range arguments can't be evaluated, then even wrapping the `Application.Vlookup` in an `IsError` function will still raise an error.

Comment: I get a runtime error 1004: Unable to get the Vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Comment: @AntónioPires most likely you have bad range construction. Please edit your question to show how you're assigning to both `CostCentreRange` and `billableRange`, and indicate which line is actually raising the error.

Comment: I have edited it. I have used this exact method to do a vlookup in different workbooks. it has always worked perfectly. But now i don't know why it is not working

Comment: i deleted the 2nd vlookuo because the first one demonstrates the problem by itself